# Colab qupa CUDA and tensorflow version compatibility

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

Trying to run code listed here: https://try.quadrant.ai/hubfs/QuPA-Documentation/rbm-example.html

Successfully installed qupa library. I think CUDA version running on Google Colab could be the error as well the not sure if tensorboard version is compatible.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

10 frames
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: How did you install the Qupa library?

Comment: from the trial... super intersted in this theory if u work for them please help me get it running?

Comment: I could not import the QuPa in my notebook. However, I think you might not have prepared your environment properly. Could you try the below command to prepare the environment then tell me if it works.

Comment: Continuing, I used the following commands to install CUDA in my notebook: `!wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin
!mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
!wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/10.2/Prod/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01_1.0-1_amd64.deb
!dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01_1.0-1_amd64.deb
!apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01/7fa2af80.pub
!apt-get update
!apt-get -y install cuda`

Comment: dpkg: error: cannot access archive '!apt-key': No such file or directory
E: The update command takes no arguments

Comment: throws this error, everything up until dpkg works fine!

Comment: Can you please have a look in the commands desaccribed [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu#before-you-begin). Remember to remove **sudo** and use **"!"** before all commands in your notebook. I have used these commands and they all worked fine.

Comment: Selecting previously unselected package cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01.
(Reading database ... 145118 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01_1.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01 (1.0-1) ...
Setting up cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01 (1.0-1) ...
E: Invalid operation add
E: The update command takes no arguments

Comment: So !apt add throws this i believe this is the source of the grief

Comment: The documentation I showed you does not mention **"apt add"**. Did you follow the steps to prepare your environment? You can go [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb#recent=true), create a new notebook and run the comment I shared above  which are taken from the documentation ( they are just all together).